# How to send multiple checkbox values to Firebase Database when a Button is clicked Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-checkbox

I want to send multiple checkbox values to Firebase database. I took three Checkboxes in XML and a Button. I want to store selected checkbox text to Firebase when the Button is clicked and go to another Activity. This is my code, but it isn't working.

```
    mFirstCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.firstCheckBox);
    mSecondCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.secondCheckBox);
    mThirdCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.thirdCheckBox);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch (view.getId()) {

                case R.id.firstCheckBox:
                    if(mFirstCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);

                        current_user_db.child("1").setValue("Compiler design");

                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.secondCheckBox:
                    if(mSecondCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);

                        current_user_db.child("2").setValue("Operating Systems");

                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.thirdCheckBox:

                    if(mThirdCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);

                        current_user_db.child("3").setValue("Software Engineering");

                    }
                    break;

            }
            Intent interestIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, InterestsActivity.class);
            interestIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(interestIntent);

        }
    });
```

This is what I want to achieve in Firebase database, but not getting. In between 'Users' and 'Values(1,2,3)' there must be user_Id. it is missing in the diagram
because I have entered them in Firebase

[image: This is what I want to achieve in Firebase Database, but not getting. In between 'Users' and 'Values(1,2,3)' there must be user_Id. it is missing in the diagram]

Please Guide me, where I am getting wrong. Tell me any other alternative to get this done, if I am completely wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you getting then?

Comment: Nothing in Firebase. just going to next activity when the button is clicked

Comment: I set up Login function for this app. I am doing this, after logging in to the app

Comment: @ThrinadhReddy Nothing in firebase will get stored because the id you are getting in switch case is of button i.e saveButton on which you have set your onclick, but you are checking whether the id is of checkbox which user has checked. Just remove switch case from Anonymous implementation of button onclick and check which checkbox is in checked state and which is not and according to  that you can send data over firebase

Comment: Thanks... It helped me...@Lucky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you are using this `view.getId()`, you are getting the id of the button that was clicked and not the id of your checkbox that was checked. Second, there is no need to use the following line of code in each case of your switch statement:

```
String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

It is enough to be used only once. In fact, there is no need to use a switch statement at all. Your code should look like this:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);

        if(mFirstCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            current_user_db.child("1").setValue("Compiler design");
        }

        if(mSecondCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            current_user_db.child("2").setValue("Operating Systems");
        }

        if(mThirdCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            current_user_db.child("3").setValue("Software Engineering");
        }

        Intent interestIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, InterestsActivity.class);
        interestIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(interestIntent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CheckBoxes only have two states - checked and unchecked, i.e. true and false. 
 Therefore, you're correct in saying a String isn't a suitable datatype 
 for holding information given by a CheckBox.
 What you want to use is a boolean.

 Treat CheckBoxes as having boolean values (the isChecked() 
 method each CheckBox has will probably come in handy), 
 and save them .
```

Comment: yes, they have only true and false. I wrote it in 'if' condition. If it is true, i want to save some value in Firebase database